# User interface does not read file

Tags: java, user-interface, io

I have created a user interface for my sound class. It looks like it should work fine because the sound class works perfectly. I'm not sure why but when i try to run the READ command, I get an error saying no such file or directory exists. The file does exist and it is in the same folder as the program. Heres the code:

```
public class SoundUI
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Sound s = new Sound();

    final String MENU = "R)ead , W)rite , B)ackwards , L)engthen , S)horten , I)ncrease Vol. ,"  +
        "D)ecrease Vol. , Q)uit";
    char cmd = ' ';

    System.out.println(MENU);
    //User interface commands for sound
    do{ 

        cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        if(cmd == 'R'){ //read
            System.out.println("Enter file name with quotes around it");
            String fileName = input.next();
            s.wavRead(fileName);
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'W'){ //save
            System.out.println("Name of file you want to save as");
            String fileName = input.next();
            s.wavSave(fileName);
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'B'){ //reverse
            s.reverse();
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'L'){ //lengthen
            s.lengthen();
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'S'){ //shorten
            s.shorten();
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'I'){ //increase volume
            System.out.println("Enter percent");
            double percent = input.nextDouble();
            s.increaseVol(percent);
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(cmd == 'D'){ //decrease volume
            System.out.println("Enter percent");
            double percent = input.nextDouble();
            s.reduceVol(percent);
            System.out.println(MENU);
            cmd = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
    } while(cmd !='Q'); //quit
}
```

}

Comment: The "with quotes around it" part sounds very suspicious to me. Are you actually using quotes, and if so, why? And what does the `wavRead` method do? You've posted your menu code, but that's not the code that's failing, presumably...

Comment: @JonSkeet I suspect it is; specifically, an input problem. The poster should print out the filename before trying to read it to see whether it's what's intended.

Comment: public void wavRead(String fileName){
        this.samples = WavIO.read(fileName);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The code must be looking at the top of the src folder. You can know which directory the code is looking at by using the following code:
 `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());`

Comment: this code doesn't work. how do i type it in exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - write out what exactly is contained in file name variable after this line.

```
String fileName = input.next();
```

Then check what happens in the s.wavRead method.
BTW, where does the Sound class comes from? Is it your class? If yes, debug the wavRead method and check what happens there.

Comment: it is my class. made it for an assignment. When i print this.samples after i read the file "bye8" it gives me an address.